# Since Winter '17 update, iframes embedded in Visualforce pages do not appear

Tags: visualforce, iframe

Since Winter '17 update, iframes embedded in Visualforce pages do not appear.
There have been no change in the VF pages, iframes etc. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do your pages have headers? The [Release Notes](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter17_release_notes.pdf) make some mention of Clickjack Protection updates for pages without a header.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. On sandbox, the VF page with the iframe renders perfectly. On production the iframe is blocked with a "Refused to display <link> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'" error.

Comment: Did you try to change the Clickjack Protection Level? In Setup -> Sites -> your site -> Edit -> ClickJack Protection Level